# C# HttpWebRequest throws exception on "wwwt" URL

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, prefix

I am trying to call external SOAP service on both in testing and production environments. Their URLs differ in one single letter: test service uses 'wwwt' prefix, while production service uses 'www' prefix.

If I call production service ('www'), I get response from server. But if I call test service ('wwwt'), WebException is thrown, stating that "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.".

This exception occurs on test service even with a bare GET request. But again, it  passes on production service: webpage contents is returned.

I suspect that the 't' is the culprit.

Due backwards compatibility I am forced to use .NET 4.5 framework.

BOTH services do work and are accessible over SOAPUI.

Minimal reproductional example:

```
//For URLs please see my comment bellow
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);            
webRequest.Method = "GET";
WebResponse wr = webRequest.GetResponse(); /*crashes here*/
```

Any suggestions?

Sorry for my english,
Marjan

Comment: If you've just created the wwwt subdomain, perhaps DNS hasn't propagated yet?

Comment: 1) Check the logs on the server, see if the request ever reached the machine, 2) That error is often caused by a firewall getting in the way: make sure this isn't happening, 3) Try and test using some other tool, see if you can establish a connection, 4) It's almost certainly not the 't'

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: URL of "defective" service is https://wwwt.ajpes.si/wsPrsInfo/PrsInfo.asmx. URL of "accessible" service is "https://www.ajpes.si/wsPrsInfo/PrsInfo.asmx". Both use HTTPS protocol. They are provided by state. I used SOAPUI for testing and they both work.

Comment: I pasted example. Works on "www", does not work on "wwwt".

Answer (score 1):

It was a

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

that saved me.